# No more state monad version of hash maps / sets in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hash, state-monad

Is the monadic interface to hash sets and maps gone in Haskell? What kind of performance model should I have in mind when using the modern versions? (Data.Map, Data.HashMap, Data.HashSet). They do not appear to have any IO code in the version I have (ghc 7.0.2),

```
> :browse Data.HashSet
type HashSet a = Set a
newtype Set a
  = Data.HashSet.Set (Data.IntMap.IntMap (Data.HashSet.Some a))
(\\) :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
delete :: (Data.Hashable.Hashable a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
difference :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
elems :: Set a -> [a]
empty :: Set a
Data.HashSet.filter :: Ord a => (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> Set a
fold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Set a -> b
fromList :: (Data.Hashable.Hashable a, Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
insert :: (Data.Hashable.Hashable a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
intersection :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
isProperSubsetOf :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool
isSubsetOf :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Bool
Data.HashSet.map ::
  (Data.Hashable.Hashable b, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
member :: (Data.Hashable.Hashable a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Bool
notMember ::
  (Data.Hashable.Hashable a, Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Bool
Data.HashSet.null :: Set a -> Bool
partition :: Ord a => (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> (Set a, Set a)
singleton :: Data.Hashable.Hashable a => a -> Set a
size :: Set a -> Int
toList :: Set a -> [a]
union :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
unions :: Ord a => [Set a] -> Set a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the monadic interface to hash sets and maps gone in Haskell?

No, there's still a monadic hash map, [Data.HashTable](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Data-HashTable.html), which lives in the `IO` monad. (It's pretty annoying that it doesn't live in the `ST` monad, but that would make it slightly less portable and slightly less easy to understand I suppose, because `ST` isn't Haskell 98.) It works pretty much like a hashtable in any imperative language. The performance characteristics should be the same as well.

And of course from any map, including a hashtable, you can create a set, by storing dummy values (e.g. just map every key to itself).

Comment: Nitpick on the whole discussion:  calling this a "monadic hash map" is pretty misleading, and I was confused by it.  I was expecting a `MonadHashTable` class or something.  I'd call it an "impure hash table" or even a "hashtable with operations in `IO`".  The word "monad" doesn't really belong here.

Comment: I don't see why. What's wrong with calling something "monadic" if has a bunch of functions which return values in a monad?

Comment: I think to call something "monadic" those functions should return results in an _arbitrary_ monad, or at least any monad in a given type class. If they return only values in `IO`, well... `IO` is a functor and a type constructor as well as a monad; why not call it "functorial" or "type constructoric"?

Comment: @Alexey I just Googled monadic. The usage of the term "monadic parsing", including in a well-cited paper by Hutton, doesn't conform to your restricted definition of the word.

Comment: I don't think the word "impurities" is any better, since state monad composition can be thought of as a pure state transformation. You can also see the point being that when things are restricted to run in sequence [in a monad], versus arbitrary leaf node evaluation permissible in pure code, the underlying implementation can be made to exhibit reasonably high performance. While I see one could read that I want a new monad exposing hash table ops, the title says "state monad" which should trigger other memories. FWIW, my point of view is that "operations" is vague and "monad" is specific.

Comment: Would you call functions that return lists monadic?  If functions returning IO are called monadic then functions returning lists should be as well.

Comment: @Robin Green: The difference in that case is that the parsers themselves define a monad. In this case, the hash map itself is not monadic, it merely has functions operating on it that produce values in a specific monad. `Maybe` implements a form of monadic error handling; is something like `Data.Map` monadic because `lookup` returns a value in `Maybe`?

Comment: @augustss: Not to mention that all Haskell types live in the " " monad, which is like `Identity` but without the `newtype` wrapper. :)

Answer (score 7):

Data.HashMap and Data.HashSet use Patricia trees to store the hash, so the performance for the operations have the same asymptotic complexity as Data.Map.  But that said, the constant factor is much smaller and they perform quite a lot faster in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

There is still [a HashTable, living in IO](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Data-HashTable.html), available. However, that one is deprecated (precisely because it is *not* living in the ST monad) and will be removed in GHC 7.8.

Yet there is a monadic hashtable available, which *is* living in ST. See the [hashtables package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables) in the hackageDB.